# Can glTexImage2D() use an already existing memory block?

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, memory-efficiency

Can I use `glTexImage2D()` and / or `glTexSubImage2D()` (or maybe there's some other method I don't know about) with an already existing block of memory, instead of always uploading the changed pixels? I already have the changed pixels somewhere in memory, and I'd like to send a pointer to that location if possible.

The problem is that I'm likely going to update a large amount of pixels, and uploading all of them introduces a lot of overhead and wasted memory. And since the application will only run on a mobile device without dedicated GPU memory, all I'm doing now is copying a big chunk of memory to another location of the same memory...

Also, I'm looking for a solution that would work on iOS devices, since the application will only run on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
But not with glTexImage2D, as the just uploads image data to the gpu.

What you can do however, is by binding the texture to a pixel buffer, and then mapping the pixel buffer to memory by using glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, ID).

This will give you a point to the pixel data.

Comment: Be aware that using a PBO will also give you a 2x memory overhead - once for the PBO and once for the texture.  Also beware of pipeline stalls when mapping.